# C# Creating Sublists from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, sublist

I have a DataTable that contains results from a SQL query.  I want to loop through the table and build sub lists based on similar results in a field. How do I do that?

For example, my DataTable has the following records.

Color, Count

Red, 1
Blue, 1
Blue, 2
Red, 2
Yellow, 1

I want to be able to group them so that my results are

List1:

Red, 1
Red, 2

List2:

Blue, 1
Blue, 2

List3:

Yellow, 1

Comment: Post what yoy have tried so far

Comment: You wan to `GroupBy` or `OrderBy` the colour?

Comment: You should use LinQ, if you already know sql is the easiest way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries

Comment: The question should be descriptive, Please add more details, What kind of solutions you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily with Linq:

```
var groups = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(z => z["Color"]).Select(z => z.ToList()).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group " + (i + 1).ToString());
    foreach (var item in groups[i])
        Console.WriteLine(item["Color"] + ",  " + item["Count"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Casting the rows with `Cast<DataRow>()` allows you to enumerate the rows with Linq. The `GroupBy()` puts the rows into groups where they share the same `Color` value. The `Select()` gets the groups as a list. The result is a list containing your groups (more specifically, a `List<List<DataRow>>()`). Modify and cast the results to fit your requirements.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I knew I needed to use Linq, but couldn't figure out the grouping and how to implement the nested loops.  Thanks!